# How to leverage idle desktop computing power to get huge tasks completed

Tags: c#, .net, grid-computing

We have a job which processes a set of items around 100,000 to compute and update various attributes of those items. When we run on Quad core Xenon server, the program takes about 40 hours finish executing. 40 hours is huge and we have necessity of finishing this job within 5 hours. All the application logic is optimized and moreover we used multiple threads with ThreadPool to leverage all the cores of the CPU.

Now we are looking into the option of Grid computing and have been researching for good and easy grid computing software as we have around 500 desktop computers that are idle for more than 12 hours in a day. We could not find anything ready-to-use framework. Please suggest any good framework preferably using .NET.

Answer (score 2):

[NGrid](http://ngrid.sourceforge.net/) looks like it might fit what you're after. It doesn't appear to be very well supported (last commit was 3 years ago), but it might provide a good starting point.

Comment: One additional note is that you may consider looking into building your own from scratch if all 500 PCs are on the same LAN. Defining a protocol atop of UDP is fairly straight forward and will pay dividends if your message structure is simple enough.

Comment: @mohang - Please be sure to followup with your findings. I'd be interested in hearing how you addressed your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [BOINC](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/).  It's been successfully used to harvest spare CPU time for years.  I've only used it as a client, not had to develop for it.  But I can say the user experience is pretty goof.

[Word Community Grid](https://secure.worldcommunitygrid.org/index.jsp) use it for various research projects.  And I guess folding@home use it too, but I didn't check.